# "/etc/sudoers is world writable” on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, iterm, sudo

I have gone through a lot of google results. Let me explain what I have tried first. I am currently working on a corporate laptop. Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6.

Error that I get:

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

ls -le /etc

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel            179 Aug 18  2018 shells
drwxrwxrwx   4 root      wheel            128 Aug 18  2018 snmp
drwxrwxrwx   5 root      wheel            160 Nov 11  2019 ssh
drwxrwxrwx   6 root      wheel            192 Nov 11  2019 ssl
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel            257 Aug 18  2018 sudo_lecture
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel           1630 Mar 11 11:51 sudoers
drwxrwxrwx   2 root      wheel             64 Aug 18  2018 sudoers.d
drwxrwxrwx   4 root      admin            128 Dec 25  2018 symantec
-rw-rw-rw-@  1 01244861  wheel             47 Feb  2 18:13 sysctl.conf
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel             96 Aug 21  2018 syslog.conf
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel           1316 Aug 18  2018 ttys
drwxrwxrwx   6 root      wheel            192 Aug 18  2018 wfs
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel              0 Aug 18  2018 xtab
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel            126 Aug 18  2018 zprofile
-rwxrwxrwx   1 root      wheel            207 Aug 18  2018 zshrc
```

I have changed permission using `chmod 440 /etc/sudoers` and `chmod 777 /etc/sudoers` and also using info and manually updating from the file properties.

[image: Mac file info]

I am using iTerm2 as my terminal.

echo $PATH

```
/Users/01244861/.yarn/bin:/Users/01244861/.nvm/versions/node/v10.13.0/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/usr/local/opt/node@10/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/go/bin
```

echo $SHELL

```
/bin/zsh
```

My user permissions:
[image: User permissions]

Is there anything else that I can do to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Well, if you change permissions what happens?

Comment: Honestly, all the permissions in /etc look strange. Any idea what could have caused this?